# "RoleType.Editor" is missing from RoleType enum : 2010 CSOM C#

Tags: 2010, permissions, roles

I am trying to assign the existing SharePoint Group Permission to my folder in `Document Libray`.

I am using following code:

```
var roletypes = clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Editor);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestLibrary1");
list.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);

RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
collRoleDefinitionBinding.Add(roletypes);
list.RoleAssignments.Add(grp, collRoleDefinitionBinding);
```

Everything is fine but the problem is when I try to select `RoleType` as `Editor`, its giving error.

So my question is what may be the possible reason for missing `RoleType.Editor`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Editor` roletype is not available in 2010, it was introduced in 2013

Compare

[RoleType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.roletype(v=office.14).aspx)
(2010)

with

[RoleType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.roletype(v=office.15).aspx)
(2013)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are missing the `Load` statement.

Try

```
clientContext.Load(roletypes);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```